# Align multi-line legend titles with math expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having difficulty properly aligning a multi-line legend title that contains math expressions:

```
# Simulate example data and create plot
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 1:3)
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) + geom_point() 

# Legend title that is causing problems:
expectation  <- bquote(paste("E(\U03BC | ", bold(Z), ", ", bold("\U03B8"), ")"))
legend_title <- bquote(paste("Prediction\n", .(expectation), sep = ""))
gg <- gg + labs(colour = legend_title) 
gg
```

[image: Example plot]

I want "Prediction" to be centred over "E(mu | Z | theta)" (or, have them both left aligned). I have tried playing with `theme()` and `guides()`, but to no avail:

```
# These approaches do not fix the problem:
gg + theme(legend.title.align = 0.5)
gg + guides(colour = guide_legend(title.hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `atop` works.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) + geom_point() + 
  labs(colour = bquote(atop("Prediction" ,paste("E(\U03BC | ", bold(Z), ", ", bold("\U03B8"), ")")))
  )
```

[image: lines]